# matplotlib axhspan and axvspan behind data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

axhspan and axvspan, by default, add the rectangles "in front" of the data. That is, alpha is set to 1.0, the data is overlapped. Is it possible to put it behind the data, so that the color of the plot is not affected? The color overlap is visible in scatter plots.

Comment: use `zorder`. Set the `zorder` of the things you want on top to be greater than the `zorder` of the things you want to be below

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html

Comment: Tom I think your comment is actually an answer